# Conditional folder creation and file upload based on error handling in PHP

Tags: php

I'm relatively new to PHP and currently working on a project where I need to create a folder and upload files based on form submissions. I've set up the process in two files: **create-resource.php** for form handling and function execution, and **create-resource-functions.php** for the actual functions like folder creation and file uploads.

- `create-resource.php`: https://pastebin.com/RaVRudTj
- `create-resource-functions.php`: https://pastebin.com/NrtPGq2N

My goal is to conditionally create the folder and upload files only if the $errors array is empty. Currently, the folder is created regardless of any errors. (And only the `.jar` file is uploaded, the images aren't and they return an error that the folder doesn't exist?)

*I'm aware that my code is all over the place and needs refinement, and I'm committed to improving it.*
*I appreciate any advice or examples you can provide. Thank you in advance for your help!*

Comment: "I'm relatively new to PHP" - major props for using prepared statements in your code!

Comment: Please post a [mre] here in the question, not links to pastebin.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by making separate functions for handling errors and doing the necessary tasks. I tweaked the code to match the rest and work correctly. I had to move some things around, but now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Function arguments flagged as byref such as `&$errors` aren't necessarily wrong, but they are a code smell for me because I personally only need to do this in exceptional situations. In your case, `create_resource_banner($resource_id, &$errors)` only uses `$errors` for checking if there was an error elsewhere which is weird and defeats encapsulation. The code that *calls* function should only do so if there are no previous errors.

So instead of this:

```php
$bannerResult = create_resource_banner($resource_id, $errors);
if ($bannerResult !== null && $bannerResult['error'] && isset($bannerResult['message'])) {
    $errors[] = $bannerResult['message'];
}
```

I'd write this:

```php
if(empty($errors)) {
    $bannerResult = create_resource_banner($resource_id);
    if ($bannerResult !== null && $bannerResult['error'] && isset($bannerResult['message'])) {
        $errors[] = $bannerResult['message'];
    }
}
```

Comment: I should add, this isn't necessarily a perfect answer to your specific problem, however the code that makes directories and deals with files is in this type of function, and these functions shouldn't even be allowed to execute if there's at least one error (per your stated logic).

Comment: Not related to your problem, and this is also just a preference, but one common pattern is to throw exceptions when a function doesn't perform a desired result, instead of returning data that the caller needs to parse the logic on. With an exception, the caller can try running it, and if it fails, grab the details of what went wrong from the exception itself. One of your functions should be written this way, for instance: https://3v4l.org/cHb4C

Comment: Hey, I just realized I forgot to check if $errors is empty before creating the folder in create_resource_file(), fixing one issue. Now, facing errors because the folder 'doesn't exist,' although it does; it seems the functions are running too soon. I'm considering ensuring the folder is created first before uploading the images, but I'm not sure how to handle this since each file has a separate function. Any suggestions?

Comment: Also, thank you for taking the time to review my code and provide feedback! I appreciate your suggestions on the error handling and will definitely consider incorporating exceptions in my functions.